# Image rotation not working on hosting environment, but works on localhost

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, gd

I'm leaning PHP and I want to rotate an image after upload. The following code works on localhost, but it is not run in the hosting environment.

```
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];); // provided that the image is jpeg. Use relevant function otherwise
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
        break;
        case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
        break;
        case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
        break;
        default:
        $image = $imageResource;
    } 
}
imagejpeg($image, $name, 60);
```

Comment: Is php linked against gdlib on your hosting server.

Comment: so, I don't know gdlib. I'am new at php

Comment: my hosting says 
GD Support enabled

Comment: Do you have the `EXIF` PHP extension added and enabled? Use the `phpinfo()` function to see a list of extensions available. Also I don't know if an syntax error was introduced while writing the question, but the first line has an extra semicolon at the end. `exif_read_data($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];);` <- There shouldn't be a semicolon after the `]` angle-bracket.

Comment: EXIF Support enabled php info says. I clean code delete semicolon but this code sometimes work sometimes not work